# ECONNREFUSED error in terminal when installing express with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: on node js command prompt i am getting following error while installing express]

I am running following command 
`npm install express`

Comment: Have you got direct Internet access?

Comment: yes,i am connecting to internet.

Comment: Ping google from this command prompt. Try to switch off the firewall. Make sure you don't use proxy. If you do, you should configure npm

Answer (score 0):

In terms of diagnosis, the error message is very clear. `199.27.76.162` is one of npmjs.org IP adresses. The `net.js` module failing with ECONNREFUSED implies that there is no connectivity from NPM to the npmjs.org server.

You should try do to a `ping` on that IP adress and verify general connectivity to that server.

If you run `ping 199.27.76.162` from the terminal you should get an output confirming there is connectivity:

```
PING 199.27.76.162 (199.27.76.162): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=131.795 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=138.581 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=132.076 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=130.904 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=132.261 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.76.162: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=131.167 ms
```

If you are using a `proxy` make sure to setup `npm` properly:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

Based on all evidence, the problem seems to be with your networking settings.

Comment: After ping to google I got following response.......                              

C:\Users>ping 199.27.76.162

Pinging 199.27.76.162 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 199.27.76.162:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users>

Comment: Yep.. that means ur computer cant connect to npmjs servers.